# Do filtered colimits commute with $\kappa$-directed limits in $\mathbf{Set}$?

Tags: category-theory

It is well known that filtered colimits commute with finite limits in $\mathbf{Set}$. It's also true that $\kappa$-filtered colimits commute with $\kappa$-small limits for any regular cardinal $\kappa$.

According to [$n$Lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/L-finite+category), it also holds that filtered colimits commute with so-called $L$-finite limits in $\mathbf{Set}$.
One definition of an $L$-finite category is that it is the target of an initial functor from a finite category.
According to that $n$Lab page, this means that any category with an initial object is an $L$-finite category.
Since any regular cardinal $\kappa$ has an initial object, it would follow that **filtered colimits commute with $\kappa$-directed limits in $\mathbf{Set}$**. I've never seen this result mentioned before, so I want to ask: Is this correct, or is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Filtered colimits commute with limits of functors $\kappa\to\mathbf{Set}$.  But the usual limits indexed by $\kappa$ you think of are of functors from $\kappa^{op}$, not from $\kappa$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, of course!

Comment: Also note that if a category $A$ has an initial object, the limit of a diagram indexed by $A$ is just the evaluation at that initial object. So $A$-indexed limits commute with *any* colimit.